# It shows null values while retrieving data from Edittext in custom alert dialogue?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I made a custom alert dialogue box that gets invoked by teacherLogin() method.
Dialogue consists of an Editext(whose value gets stored in "text" String) and two buttons i.e. "Login" & "Cancel". When pressed Login button it shows null value of String "text". Please help iff possible??

```
public void teacherLogin(View view)
{

    View alertview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert,null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Login");
    builder.setView(alertview);


    final String text = ((EditText) alertview.findViewById(R.id.date_text)).getText().toString();

    builder.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name:"+text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i)
        {
            Snackbar.make(findViewById(android.R.id.content), "Dialogue Cancelled", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply because you are getting the text from the `EditText` before the dialogue is shown.

This works:

```
 private void showDialog() {

    View alertview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Login");
    builder.setView(alertview);


    final EditText editText = ((EditText) alertview.findViewById(R.id.date_text));

    builder.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name:" + editText.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you initialize `text` variable before user presses `Login` button of the alert dialogue. Initialize it inside listener of positive `Login` button.

```
private void showDialog() {

View alertview = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null);

AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Login");
builder.setView(alertview);


final EditText textEditText = ((EditText) alertview.findViewById(R.id.date_text));

builder.setPositiveButton("Login", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        String textValue = textEditText.getText().toString();

        if(textValue!=null && !textValue.isEmpty(){
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "name:" +textValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
         //show empty value toast to user
        else{
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          //dismiss dialog
          dialogInterface.dismiss();
       }
    }
    });

builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //dismiss dialog
        dialogInterface.dismiss();
    }
});

AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Glad to help, Please mark as answer or upvote if it helped.
Thank you.